# Context issue whilst adding IUndoableOperation to my EditorPart

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I was following the example described in http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/wrkAdv_undo.htm

in the `init()` method of my `EditorPart`

```
    /**
     * @see org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart#init(org.eclipse.ui.IEditorSite,
     * org.eclipse.ui.IEditorInput)
     */
    @Override
    public void init(IEditorSite site,IEditorInput input)
    throws PartInitException {
        ...
        IWorkbench workbench = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getWorkbench();
        myUndoContext= workbench.getOperationSupport().getUndoContext();


        UndoRedoActionGroup historyActionGroup = new UndoRedoActionGroup(site, myUndoContext, true);
        historyActionGroup.fillActionBars(site.getActionBars());
        }
```

... I added the following to a method in my `EditorPart`

```
        IUndoableOperation operation = new MyOperation("My Action");
        operation.addContext(myUndoContext);
        try {
            IStatus status = OperationHistoryFactory.getOperationHistory().execute(operation, null, null);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I was able to add undo actions but I noticed that the undo actions gets added to all files opened by my custom editor. When I make changes to a file, all other opened files gets the undo operation added to the edit menu. How can I make it only applicable to the currently active file?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this line:

```
  myUndoContext= workbench.getOperationSupport().getUndoContext();
```

This gives you an undo context which is for the whole workbench. I think you need an undo context which is specific to your editor. `org.eclipse.core.commands.operations.ObjectUndoContext` looks suitable. It is probably enough just to do

```
  myUndoContext = new ObjectUndoContext(this);
```

although many of the uses in the Eclipse editors use and document or undo manager as the object.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the undo button becomes disabled once I navigate away from the editor.

Comment: That is normal behavior in most editors, it should enable again when the editor gains focus.

Comment: I meant, it's disabled when I revisit the editor after navigating away.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed similar problem just a minute ago. My problem was following: UndoRedo actions were appearing for all opened editors. The reason was, that `UndoActionHandler` and `RedoActionHandler` were created and added for each editor, like this:

```
if (undoCmdHandler == null || !contains(undoCmdHandler)) {
    undoCmdHandler = new UndoActionHandler(site, undoContext);
    actionBars.getToolBarManager().add(undoCmdHandler);
}
```

**#contains()** method was always returning false (since it was buggy), so the handler was always created. So, I removed it:)

In your example you also always create `UndoRedoActionGroup` for each editor and fill action bars with it. I would suggest you not to use action group, but rather create `UndoActionHandler` and `RedoActionHandler` by yourself, as shown above.

I you have control over your handlers, then the solution is to create only one instance of `UndoActionHandler` and `RedoActionHandler`, fill actions bar with it, but when your context changes (when user navigates between editors (you should listen to this event) ) just update context on your Handler, like this:

```
redoCmdHandler.setContext(undoContext);
```

So, in the end you would end up with something similar:

```
public static RedoActionHandler getRedoActionHandler(IWorkbenchPartSite site, IActionBars actionBars, IUndoContext undoContext) {
        if (redoCmdHandler == null) {
            redoCmdHandler = new RedoActionHandler(site, undoContext);
            actionBars.getToolBarManager().add(redoCmdHandler);
        } else {
            redoCmdHandler.setContext(undoContext);
        }
        return redoCmdHandler;
    }
```